# Define different DataTemplate for same source

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I'm trying to show collection of bool with a DataTemplate for ListView.
Here's the code:

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>       
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemCheckBoxTemplate">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemRadioButtonTemplate">
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <TextBlock Text="ListViewSample" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemCheckBoxTemplate}" Grid.Column="1"/>                    
</Grid>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();  
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private List<bool> myBooleanCollection;
    public List<bool> MyData
    {
        get { return myBooleanCollection;  }
        set { myBooleanCollection = value; }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        myBooleanCollection = new List<bool>();
        myBooleanCollection.Add(true);
        myBooleanCollection.Add(false);
        myBooleanCollection.Add(true);
        myBooleanCollection.Add(true);
        myBooleanCollection.Add(false);            
    }
}
```

Instead of ItemTemplate ListItemCheckBoxTemplate I want to apply ListItemRadioButtonTemplate with Radio button. How I can specify the use of ItemTemplate for the same source in xaml. Do I need to change the DataSource for the same or
do I have some way to specify the DataTemplate in xaml based on condition.

Comment: What is the condition? Do you want to do it in code or XAML?

Comment: I don't want to change the source. I want to do it any how in xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify what is the condition on which you want to change template but you can add another property to your view model, say `AllowMultiple`:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private List<bool> myBooleanCollection;

   public List<bool> MyData
   {
      get { return myBooleanCollection;  }
      set { myBooleanCollection = value; }
   }

   private bool _allowMultiple;

   public bool AllowMultiple
   {
      get { return _allowMultiple; }
      set
      {
         if (_allowMultiple != value)
         {
            _allowMultiple = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllowMultiple");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and then change `ListBox.Style` to:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
   <ListBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
         <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListItemCheckBoxTemplate}"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AllowMultiple}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListItemRadioButtonTemplate}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

assuming that `ViewModel` implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) you can then change `ItemTemplate` buy changing `AllowMultiple` against view model

Answer (score 1):

You can specify DataTemplate for each item with the followign attribute:

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemCheckBoxTemplate}
```

Change this to:

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemRadioButtonTemplate}
```

If you need multiple item templates in the same ListBox then you can provide custom template selection logic via the [DataTemplateSelector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want to do it in Xaml, you will need to expose property which you can bind to as a selector. Have a look at [A Data Template Selector in Xaml](http://breakingdotnet.blogspot.nl/2012/05/data-template-selector-in-xaml.html)

Comment: Thanks Michal your post also helped me ! but please remove ItemTemplate assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You need create `DataTemplateSelector` and using this for [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You also need to determine the condition under which you will return the `DataTemplate`. Example:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow" ...
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OneTemplate">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">            
    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <this:MyItemTemplateSelector OneTemplate="{StaticResource OneTemplate}" 
                                     SecondTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}" />            
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ListBox>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public class MyItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate OneTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SecondTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        bool myItem = (bool)item;

        if (myItem == true)
        {
            return OneTemplate;
        }

        return SecondTemplate;
    }
}
```